# Modifying CSS for a nicer looking loading spinner

Tags: css, angularjs, spinner, loading

I am a 100% newbie to CSS and have been trying to modify the existing CSS in angular-loading-bar module to have a nicer-looking loading spinner. So far, I have a square-shape spinner that spins in the center of the webpage, with a black top border and grey border on the left.

It does not look the way I wanted. I would like a circle spinner, but can't figure out where I can modify to make it a circular shape. Could someone help?

```
#loading-bar-spinner {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: 350ms linear all;
  -moz-transition: 350ms linear all;
  -o-transition: 350ms linear all;
  transition: 350ms linear all;
}

#loading-bar-spinner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

#loading-bar-spinner .spinner-icon {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;

  border:  solid 4px transparent;
  border-top-color:  #000;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 14px;

  -webkit-animation: loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:    loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:     loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  -o-animation:      loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  animation:         loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
  0%   { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
  0%   { -o-transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -o-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-ms-keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
  0%   { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Comment: Set the border-radius to 50% rather than 14px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#loading-bar-spinner .spinner-icon {
    border-radius: 50%; /* Change to 50% from 14px; */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q6u8p48y/

Comment: thanks, appreciate it. I made the spinner look slower by changing from 400ms to 1s.